# How to change the input text color of a form

Tags: javascript, css

I know this is a trivial question, since it should be basic CSS, but for some reason the color of the text is not changing for me.  I am trying to change the input text color to gray (#d6d6d6), but nothing changes.  I've even placed an !important value to try and overwrite Chrome's User Agent Stylesheet, but still no go.  Am I missing something here?

[image]

```js
if (event.target.name === 'target') {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  if (event.target.value === 'true') {
    for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
      if (inputs[i].name === 'something') {
        inputs[i].style.border = '1px solid #dee1e5';
        inputs[i].classList.add('disabled');
        inputs[i].previousSibling.style.color = '#dee1e5';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
input[type='text'].disabled {
  color: #d6d6d6 !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="something" class="disabled" style="border: 1px solid ;">
```

**UPDATE**

Apparently the Chrome autofill feature was causing the issue: input:-internal-autofill-selected

Comment: Please show how you're getting the `inputs` array

Comment: What you posted does create gray text. This is currently not reproducable.

Comment: As a side note: if you actually want to disable the input you need to use the [disabled attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#disabled).

Comment: So, as of right now, the Chrome browser is not changing the text color, which is why I'm posting this question.  Also, I tried adding the 'disabled' attribute, but by doing so disabled styling as well, from what I've read.

Comment: inspect your element and see what is overriding the style - as you can see from the snippet of your code, it works fine in chrome

Comment: can u share a screenshot?

Comment: @Pete yeah, I tried that and it's the User Agent Stylesheet adding !important to it's own style, but even when I add !important to my own, it still doesn't change the text color.  This is just weird and frustrating.

Comment: Ok disable all your browser plugins and addons - sounds like you have an auto complete plugin (or something similar) styling it - chrome does not colour inputs - it may add padding and border colours, but it does not change the text colour

Comment: I doubt it myself, but just to be sure: That `<input>` isn't placed inside an `<iframe>` or something?

Comment: Man, I'm such an idiot.  I was using the autocomplete feature within Chrome and it was styling the text for me.  Once I deleted the text and filled it in myself, the text was colored as expected.  My bad guys.  I would like to disable that feature.

Comment: @zer00ne I'm using .previousSibling to styling the <label> that sites before the <input>.  Also, I'm using React, which sends all values as string no matter what.  Once you receive the value, you can then convert it to whatever you need it to be.